# Axios post with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I have the problem that my param articleid is not passed to my route /createAnswer. When i here log my articleData._id it is the required id (e.g 60b4f5d8c8be1d4cb0cdd6ca) that i will pass to my route /createAnswer.

```
const createAnswer = () => {
    axios.get('/getUserByFirebaseid', {
        params: {
            firebaseid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const userData = response.data[0];
        console.log(articleData._id);
        axios({
            url: '/createAnswer',
            method: 'post',
            params: {
                articleid: articleData._id
            },
            data: {
                content: editorContent,
                creator: userData._id,
                voting: 0
            }
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Answer successfully created");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Answer is not successfully created", error);
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Userdata are not loaded", error);
    })
}
```

But when i log here my articleid it is **undefined**.

```
router.post('/createAnswer', (req, res) => {
    console.log("ArticleId: ", req.params.articleid);
    console.log("Answerdata: ", req.body);
    const answerData = req.body;
    const newAnswer = Answer(answerData);
    newAnswer.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ msg: "Internal server error" });
        } else {
            res.json({ msg: "Answer successfully write to MongoDB" });
        }
    });
});
```

How do i become the id in my route /createAnswer? I have also tried to log req.body.articleid but with the same result (undefined). I have also searched here by stackoverflow for a solution but i don't find a solution that worked for me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you seen this article? - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-params-property/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simplecreators link it worked the solution for the problem is the following code:

```
const createAnswer = () => {
    axios.get('/getUserByFirebaseid', {
        params: {
            firebaseid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const userData = response.data[0];
        console.log(articleData._id);
        axios({
            url: `/createAnswer/${articleData._id}`,
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                content: editorContent,
                creator: userData._id,
                voting: 0
            }
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Answer successfully created");
            //toArticle.push("/article");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Answer is not successfully created", error);
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Userdata are not loaded", error);
    })
}
```

The articleData._id is passed after the /createAnswer route.

Notice the ` not ' !

And in the router code add the following to the route /createAnswer/:articleid. Now it shows the passed id in the logging.

```
router.post('/createAnswer/:articleid', (req, res) => {
    console.log("ArticleId: ", req.params.articleid);
    console.log("Answerdata: ", req.body);
    const answerData = req.body;
    const newAnswer = Answer(answerData);
    newAnswer.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ msg: "Internal server error" });
        } else {
            res.json({ msg: "Answer successfully write to MongoDB" });
        }
    });
});
```